# How to allow IAM users to setup their own virtual MFA devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I want to let my IAM users to setup their own MFA devices, through the console, is there a single policy that I can use to achieve this?

So far I can achieve this through a number of IAM policies, letting them list all mfa devices and list users (so that they can find themselves in the IAM console and ...

I am basically looking for a more straight forward way of controlling this.

I should add that my IAM users are trusted users, so I don't have to (although it will be quite nice) lock them down to the minimum possible, so if they can see a list of all users that is ok.

Answer (score 3):

AWS docs provide an example of how to do this under "Allow Users to Manage Only Their Own Virtual MFA Devices":

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions_examples.html#creds-policies-mfa-console

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToCreateEnableResyncTheirOwnVirtualMFADevice",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
        "iam:EnableMFADevice",
        "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToDeactivateDeleteTheirOwnVirtualMFADevice",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:DeactivateMFADevice",
        "iam:DeleteVirtualMFADevice"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:mfa/${aws:username}",
        "arn:aws:iam::account-id-without-hyphens:user/${aws:username}"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": true
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUsersToListMFADevicesandUsersForConsole",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:ListMFADevices",
        "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
        "iam:ListUsers"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

To find your AWS account ID number to plugin in in the AWS Management Console, click on Support in the navigation bar in the upper-right, and then click Support Center. Your currently signed in account ID appears below the Support menu.

See also https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/Tx2SJJYE082KBUK/How-to-Delegate-Management-of-Multi-Factor-Authentication-to-AWS-IAM-Users

Answer (score 1):

> [...] is there a single policy that I can use to achieve this?...
>
> So far I can achieve this through a number of IAM policies, [...]
>
> I am basically looking for a more straight forward way of controlling this.

I'm afraid your current approach is the only feasible one at this point, see my related answer to the more generic question [How can I give an AWS IAM user permissions to manage his own security credentials?](https://serverfault.com/a/557383/10305), which refers to another one concerning [IAM access to EC2 REST API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19891729/45773) in turn, where I explore 'IAM Credentials Self Management' in general.